Formating custom list of examples (tocloft)
I'm writing a manual using the scrbook class, and I'm using a list of examples customized with tocloft.
It works fine, but the format of the list is not identical with the list of figures: seems that "list of figures" lines are indented, and numbers are spaced from the text, which is not the case for the customized list...
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{mwe, lipsum}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\newcommand{\listexamplename}{List of Examples}
\newlistof{example}{exp}{\listexamplename}
\newcommand{\example}[1]{%
    \refstepcounter{example}
    \par\noindent\textbf{Example \theexample. #1}
    \addcontentsline{exp}{example}
    {\protect\numberline{\thechapter.\theexample}#1}\par}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    
    \listoffigures
    \listofexample
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \chapter{First topic}
    \lipsum[1]
    
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\columnwidth]{example-image}
        \caption{Figure 1 caption}
        \label{fig-1}
    \end{figure}
    
    \example{First example}
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \chapter{Second topic}
    
    \lipsum[2]
    
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\columnwidth]{example-image}
        \caption{Figure 2 caption}
        \label{fig-1}
    \end{figure}
    
    \example{Second example}
    
\end{document}

I haven't managed to fix the format of the examples list: I suppose one have to use commands like cftbeforeXskip, where X refers to part/chap/sec/ but I can't find a way to adapt it to my custom list and make all the lists have the same format?
Thanks for any help ;)

Shouldn't the second example should be numbered 2.1 rather than 2.2? I think \newlistof{example}{exp}{\listexamplename and {\protect\numberline{\thechapter.\theexample}#1}\par} are slightly incorrect. Wouldn't \newlistof[chapter]{example}{exp}{\listexamplename and {\protect\numberline{\theexample}#1}\par} be more appropriate?

You should get a warning about using tocloft with scrbook.

To make the example list have the same format as the figure list you can make the parameters used by the first list the same as those used in the second list.

\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{mwe, lipsum}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\newcommand{\listexamplename}{List of Examples}
\newlistof{example}{exp}{\listexamplename}
\newcommand{\example}[1]{%
    \refstepcounter{example}
    \par\noindent\textbf{Example \theexample. #1}
    \addcontentsline{exp}{example}
    {\protect\numberline{\thechapter.\theexample}#1}\par}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    
%   \listoffigures
%   \listofexample
    
    %****************************************************  added <<<<
        \setlength{\cftexamplenumwidth}{\cftfignumwidth} 
        \setlength{\cftexampleindent}{\cftfigindent}
        
        \begingroup % see http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tocloft/tocloft.pdf page #12
            \renewcommand*{\addvspace}[1]{}
            \listoffigures
            \listofexample
        \endgroup
    %****************************************************    
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \chapter{First topic}
    \lipsum[1]
    
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\columnwidth]{example-image}
        \caption{Figure 1 caption}
        \label{fig-1}
    \end{figure}
    
    \example{First example}
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \chapter{Second topic}
    
    \lipsum[2]
    
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\columnwidth]{example-image}
        \caption{Figure 2 caption}
        \label{fig-1}
    \end{figure}
    
    \example{Second example}
    
\end{document}


This is perfect ! I was lost with all the format parameters available in tocloft
Many thanks ;)

This example results in a very large warning about using tocloft together with a KOMA-Script class.

That's right, dunno why actually. But doesn't seems harmfull to my generated pdf

Example without package tocloft:
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{mwe,lipsum}

\KOMAoptions{
  listof=leveldown,
  listof=nochaptergap
}
%\setuptoc{toc}{leveldown}
\DeclareNewTOC[
  type=example,
  tocentrynumwidth:=figure,
  tocentryindent:=figure
]{exp}
\newcounter{example}

\newcommand{\example}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{example}%
  \par\noindent\textbf{Example \theexample. #1}%
  \addxcontentsline{exp}{example}[\thechapter.\theexample\autodot]{#1}%
  \par
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listofexamples% <- changed

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\chapter{First topic}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\columnwidth]{example-image}
    \caption{Figure 1 caption}
    \label{fig-1}
\end{figure}

\example{First example}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\chapter{Second topic}
\lipsum[2]

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\columnwidth]{example-image}
    \caption{Figure 2 caption}
    \label{fig-2}
\end{figure}

\example{Second example}
\end{document}


Just a note, because it is not clear from the question: If \example should be a kind of heading and page breaks should be avoided after it, if would AFAIK be better to use \DecareNewSectionCommand for the definition of \example. To then write into exp file instead of toc file, you would also need to redefine \addexampletocentry. Alternatively \@afterheading could be used in the definition or it could be done using \minisec.

Thanks. Will try to integrate this. Actually, I'm not sure to understand why it should be important to avoid tocloft. Don't remember exactly, but i think I used it at first because i wanted to clear list titles as I format each list (tables, figures and examples) in a dedicated chapter.
Had the idea to integrate a dedicated custom "List of examples" later in my plan. That's where the format problem appeared...
